# iOS how to explicitly request permission for bluetooth background operation mode ? (CBPeripheralManagerAuthorizationStatus)

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an app that runs in `bluetooth-peripheral` mode and waits for connections. I want to explicitly trigger the iOS permissions alert dialog on a separate page which allows the user to grant/restore permissions. (As opposed to the alert popping up as the bluetooth server is started).

**How do I explicitly force the bluetooth-peripheral iOS permissions alert to pop up (CBPeripheralManagerAuthorizationStatus) ?**

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I can use the same code I use to monitor bluetooth status to request permission:

```
func requestBluetoothPermission() {

    let showPermissionAlert = 1
    let options = [CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey: showPermissionAlert]
    bluetoothPeripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: options)

}
```